# UI COLLECTION VIEW - how to set accessory type check mark / discloser on UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Like in ui table view

i ***`need to set accessory type check mark on  UICollectionView`***

There is no property like **setAccessoryType**

**is there any other property to set accessory type for UICollectionView?**

Comment: You could maintain your own custom accessory view and hide/show it when you needed.

Comment: Here you have the code for the standard checkmark! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977527/how-do-i-display-the-standard-checkmark-on-a-uicollectionviewcell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No CollectionCell have not accessory type property.so you have to make checkmark custom way.

[image]

[UICollectionCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_6)