# Adding a badge or icon to a uicollectionviewcell?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uicollectionviewcell, badge

I found this on stack:

[How do I display the standard checkmark on a UICollectionViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977527/how-do-i-display-the-standard-checkmark-on-a-uicollectionviewcell)

But I'm a little confused on how to implement it. (I need 50 rep to ask in the comments)

I'm building a collection view where it displays a grid of images and adds a tag/badge/icon to the cell based on a variable in SQLite3?

How can i make this happen? thanks!

Keith