# How to show check tick mark in Collection view (images)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, checkmark

In Table view we can put checkmark easily on cells.

But in Collection View how can we put check mark, when we select a cell (image)?

I just took a image view inside the cell and image view and put a tick mark image. My code is below.

But it's not working.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

   //  handle tap events
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! customCollectionViewCell


    if(cell.checkMarkImage.hidden == true)
    {
        print("Hidden")
       cell.checkMarkImage.hidden = false

    }
    else
    {
         cell.checkMarkImage.hidden = true
        print("No Hidden")
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977527/how-do-i-display-the-standard-checkmark-on-a-uicollectionviewcell

Comment: Short answer you cant, you either create your custom cell, or try to find a third party cell somewhere on the internet

Comment: Ok  
Thanks @sken3r.MI

Comment: Thanks @Ujjwal
This Link will Give me Hint.

Comment: custom cell + delegate (optional, only if you want to get update immediately when the tick changed its state);

Answer (score 4):

//Delegate Method cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
UICollectionViewCell
{
    //Get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
                                                            "pickSomecell",
                   forIndexPath: indexPath) as! pickSomeGridViewController

    //Show Images in grid view
    cell.cellImage.image = self.arrAllOriginalImages[indexPath.row]
                                                            as? UIImage        

    //Check Mark toggle.
    cell.toggleSelected()      

    //return cell.
    return cell
}
```

And in pickSomeGridViewController show checkMark image selected or not.

```
class pickSomeGridViewController: UICollectionViewCell{
//Outlet of cell image.
@IBOutlet var cellImage: UIImageView!

//Outlet of checkMark image.
@IBOutlet var cellCheckMarkImage: UIImageView!

//Function  for select and deselect checkmark.
  func toggleSelected ()
  {
    //If image is selected.
    if (selected)
    {
            //Show check mark image.
            self.cellCheckMarkImage.hidden = false           
    }   

    else
    {
             //Hide check mark image.
            self.cellCheckMarkImage.hidden = true            
    }
  }   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two main problems with this code:

1. You use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` method which obtains *different* cell from collection view cache, not the one on screen.
   Use `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method of collection view instead.
2. You try to save cell's state (selected/not selected) in the cell itself. It's common mistake when working with `UITableView`/`UICollectionView` and this approach will not work. Instead, keep the state in some other place (in dictionary, for example) and *restore* it every time collection view calls your data source `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Yes I will try .
So i have to use cellForItemAtIndexPath method ?  
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

var arrData = NSMutableArray()
   // 1.Make a ModalClass.swift and NSArray with modal class objects like this

```
 class CustomModal: NSObject {
        //Declare bool variable for select  and deselect login
        var is_selected = Bool()
        //you can declare other variable also
        var id = Int32()

}




// 2. custom array with modal objects

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let arrTemp = NSArray()
        arrTemp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        for i in 0 ..< arrTemp.count{
            let eventModal = CustomModal()
            eventModal.is_selected = false
            eventModal.id = arrTemp[i] 
            arrData.add(eventModal)
        }
        tblView.reloadData()

    }
```

// 2. Use collection view delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let modal = arrData[indexPath.row] as! CustomModal()
    modal.is_selected = true
    self.arrData.replaceObject(at: indexPath.row, with: modal)

    tblView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let modal = arrData[indexPath.row] as! CustomModal()
    modal.is_selected = false
    self.arrData.replaceObject(at: indexPath.row, with: modal)

    tblView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass
    let modal = arrData[indexPath.row] as! CustomModal
    if modal.is_selected == true{
        cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named:"selected_image")
    }else{
        cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named:"deselected_image")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kishor, paintcode is the third party tool through which you can do that. I have provided the link too. since by default you don't have this facility, you should make your custom behavior to achiever this. Thanks.

Comment: But How Can we Put it in Grid View ?  
 We Are Creating  Only Check Mark Right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

In ViewController

```
// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCollectionViewCellID", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! YourCollectionViewCell
    cell.someImageView.image = imgArr[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourCollectionViewCell
    cell?.isSelected = true
    cell?.toggleSelected()    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourCollectionViewCell
    cell?.isSelected = false
    cell?.toggleSelected()
}
```

In YourCollectionViewCell

```
class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var someImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkImageView: UIImageView!

    //Function  for select and deselect checkmark.
    public func toggleSelected() {

        if (isSelected == false) {

            //Hide check mark image.
            self.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "unCheckImage")
            isSelected = true
        }else{

            //Show check mark image.
            self.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "CheckImage")
            isSelected = false
        }
    }    
}
```

Hope enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedCellIndex:Int?
```

take variable if you want to show selected Item after reloadData() : which is previously selected CellItem. {inspired by above answer }

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColorCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ColorCollectionCell

        cell.isSelected = false

        if selectedCellIndex == indexPath.item {
            cell.checkMarkImgView.image = UIImage(named: "icn_checkMark")
        }else {
            cell.toggleSelected()
        }

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ColorCollectionCell
        cell.isSelected = true
        selectedCellIndex = indexPath.item
        cell.toggleSelected()
}
```

In CollectionViewCell u can use this method

```
class ColorCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellimgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkMarkImgView: UIImageView!

     func toggleSelected() {

        if (isSelected) {
            self.checkMarkImgView.image = UIImage(named: "icn_checkMark")
        }else{
            self.checkMarkImgView.image = UIImage(named: "")
// here you can use uncheck img here i am not using any image for not selected.
        }
    }   
}
```