# UICollectionViewCell checkmark return nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, checkmark

i tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426809/8766540) 
But when i do `cell.checkmarkView.checked = true` it returns nil so everything crash.
Here is my MyCollectionViewCell:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

var checkmarkView: SSCheckMark!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    checkmarkView = SSCheckMark(frame: CGRect(x: frame.width-40, y: 10, width: 35, height: 35))
    checkmarkView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    contentView.addSubview(checkmarkView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}}
```

Could you help me understand what is wrong?

My collectionView cellforitemat...

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.listCivics()[indexPath.item]
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.checkmarkView.checked = true
    return cell
}
```

Comment: "cell.checkmarkView.checked = true it returns nil" What returns nil? Did you entered `override init(frame: CGRect) {`?

Comment: if you are talking about MyCollectionViewCell yes, i did as you can see

Comment: BTW: It's better to use the `bounds` of the content view instead of `frame`, and you should set the `autoresizingMask`. I will update my answer appropriately.

Comment: Don't comment out  `fatalError` lines. They **do** matter to discover errors like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell is loaded from storyboard. Thus, `init(frame:)` is not called. You should initialize your checkmark in `init(coder:)` as well.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let contentBounds = contentView.bounds
    checkmarkView = SSCheckMark(frame: CGRect(x: contentBounds.width - 40, y: 10, width: 35, height: 35))
    checkmarkView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    // adapt to changes in cell size
    checkmarkView.autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin ] 
    contentView.addSubview(checkmarkView)
}
```